# How to get Hourly and 16-day weather forecast using openweathermap api and http package

Tags: flutter, dart, openweathermap, forecast

i have no problem printing the jsonDecoded weather data when i'm replacing APIkey and longitude&latitude in the current weather http request. but i somehow get {cod: 401, message: Invalid API key.} error using them for getting Hourly and 16 day weather data with the same lon &lat and APIkey. heres my code:

```
 Future<dynamic> getHourlyWeather() async {
        Location location = Location();
        await location.getCurrentLocation();

        http.Response response = await http.get(
            'https://pro.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/hourly?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$APIkey');

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          String data = response.body;
          return jsonDecode(data);
        } else {
          print(response.statusCode);
        }
      }

    Future<dynamic> get16DaysWeather() async {
        Location location = Location();
        await location.getCurrentLocation();

        http.Response response = await http.get(
            'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&cnt=10&appid=$APIkey');

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          String data = response.body;
          return jsonDecode(data);
        } else {
          print(response.statusCode);
        }
      }
```

---

```
 void initState() {
    gethourly();
    super.initState();
  }


  void gethourly() async {
    var hourly = await weather.getHourlyWeather();
    print(hourly);
  }
```

Comment: is it ok that one api url is `https://pro....` and another one is `https://api....` ?

Comment: You may want to re-check your Key & it's access on OpenWeather as well.

Comment: yes on the website it says (pro. ...) for hourly but i tried both api and pro as well

Comment: i have checked alot i have the key as a constant and when i use it for getting the current weather it works, but for getting hourly and daily weather it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that getting hourly and daily weather data from openweathermap requires paid subscription.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using onecall endpoint, this endpoint provides both hourly and daily weather:

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?&units=metric&exclude=minutely&appid=${appKey}&lat=${cityData.coord.lat}&lon=${cityData.coord.lon}`;